# Liberty 8.5.5.5 Dynamic Routing didn't work

Tags: websphere-liberty

Recently I set up a Liberty ND version 8.5.5.5. I have created a collective controller and a replica controller. Each controller has a member, each member has deployed a web application. Two members as a cluster which is "myCluster".

I am using

```
./dynamicRouting genPluginCfg --port=9443 --host=liberty-cluster03.cn.ibm.com --use=admin --password=adminpwd --pluginInstallRoot=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/ --webServerNames=ihsserver1
```

to generate a `plugin-cfg.xml`, then I copy it to the plugin location,
Also have generated the key, use gskcmd and converted it to a supported key format.

When I trying use "http://ihserver-hostname/DownloadNow" to redirect to "http://app-host/DownloadNow", it give me 404 error.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out under the help of liberty developer, the reason http redirect is not working is that I started or stopped the system apache server instead of IHS, once I went to the IBM HTTP Server bin folder to start the IHS, worked!!